# fancybox with AJAX is not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, popup, fancybox

I am using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) jquery.I have a link when I click on this link at that time I retrieve images via AJAX.I want these images open in Fancybox directly.

This is my html code-

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0); id="Delhi" class="store_pictures_click">Store Pictures</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0); id="Mumbai" class="store_pictures_click">Store Pictures</a>
    <div id="storeModal"></div>
```

This is my jquery code--

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.store_pictures_click').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var store_name  =   $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('<?php echo site_url("cart/change_store_pictures"); ?>',{store_name:store_name},
            function(data){

                $('#storeModal').html(data);
                $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            }
        );

    });

});
```

This is my PHP code-

```
$store_name =   $this->input->post('store_name');
        $this->load->model('Store_Pictures_model'); 
        $data['store_pictures'] =   $this->Store_Pictures_model->get_store_pictures($store_name);

        echo '<p>';
        foreach($data['store_pictures'] as $store_picture){
            ?>

            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/full/'.$store_picture->store_picture); ?>" ></a>
        <?php
        }

        echo '</p>';
```

But I am not able to see popup of fancybox with slider.Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Fancybox is opening or not?

Comment: @Nil'z opening means??? I have included both the files fancybox.js and fancybox.css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changes in the view:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>cart/change_store_pictures/Delhi" id="Delhi" class="store_pictures_click">Store Pictures</a>
<a href="<?=base_url()?>cart/change_store_pictures/Mumbai" id="Mumbai" class="store_pictures_click">Store Pictures</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $(".store_pictures_click").fancybox({
        type        : 'iframe',
        autoSize : false,
        /*beforeLoad : function() {                    
            this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));  
            this.height = parseInt(this.href.match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
            //this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('.fancybox-skin').width();
            //this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('.fancybox-skin').height();
        },*/
        width    : "710px",
        height   : "290px",
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        //padding         : 0,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade'
    });
});

</script>
```

Your controller:

```
function change_store_pictures(){
    $store_name =   $this->uri->segment( 3 );
    $this->load->model('Store_Pictures_model'); 
    $data['store_pictures'] =   $this->Store_Pictures_model->get_store_pictures($store_name);
    $this->load->view("pic_popup", $data);
}
```

Your pic_popup.php:

```
<?php
    //print_r( $store_picture ); 
?>
<a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/full/'.$store_picture->store_picture); ?>" >
    <img src="<?=base_url('uploads/images/full/'.$store_picture->store_picture)?>">
</a>
```

Hope it helps. :D

Comment: now popup is coming but it is not showing images it is just blank.

Comment: When I am viewing in firebug it has the following html in iframe.<iframe id="fancybox-frame1382439406174" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" hspace="0" vspace="0" name="fancybox-frame1382439406174" src="http://www.witsserver.in/projects/address-home/index.php/cart/new_change_store_pictures/Delhi">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.witsserver.in/projects/address-home/uploads/images/full/store-picture.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>

Comment: In popup.php you have not added any `<img> tag`. Just showing you the link. See the above update on `pic_popup.php`.

Comment: thanks we got success in one step. Now image is visible but I have one more problems.It is not coming in slider means there must be a forward and Previous button also it should be automatic move slides (images).

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you. For slider you need to  add some slider plugin in your view. Google for `nivoslider`.

Comment: Fancybox also works for it.It has buttons of prev and next.This time scroll bar is coming and all the images are coming together.

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta:  Yes, sure you can use `fancybox` for image gallery slider too. Anyways best of luck and accept the answer if it helped you anyhow. :D

Comment: I appreciate your answer thanks for it but just showing image was not my question I need to show image in fancybox with slider is the main problem for me.Otherwise I was already showing image in popup having style like fancybox.I will dfntly accept your answer but once it will complete my question.Please help me frend.

Comment: man I was just going to accept your answer for your help but I think u make it negative thats not good.